# Access tasks results launched by other tasks in Dask

Tags: dask, distributed

My application requires me to launch tasks from within other tasks, like the following

```
def a():
    # ... some computation ..

def b():
    # ... some computation ..

def c():
    client = get_client()
    a = client.submit(a)
    b = client.submit(b)

    [a,b] = client.gather([a,b])

    return a+b

client = get_client()
res = client.submit(c)
```

However, I would like to have access to the intermediate results `a` and `b` (when calling `c`), but only c shows up in `client.futures`.

Is there a way to tell dask to keep the results for `a` and `b`?

I have tried to use the `Future.add_done_callback` method but it does not work for `submit` calls inside other `submit` calls.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at Dask's coordination primitives like shared variables, queues, and pub/sub.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html#coordination-primitives